# LiveScript with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, livescript

I wonder if there is an easy way to get LiveScript files compiled to js in Meteor.js app. Found this mrt extension:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/livescript-latest

But doing `mrt add livescript-latest` only gives error:

```
While building package `livescript-latest`:
package.js:3:9: Package.register_extension() is no longer supported. Use Package._transitional_registerBuildPlugin instead.
```

In the git repo of this extension the error is already fixed. So I can this directly to smart.json:

```
"livescript-latest": {
      "git": "https://github.com/Whoaa512/meteor-livescript.git",
      "branch": "master"
    }
```

This seems to be installed fine, but when I try adding .ls files to the project, they are not seems to be compiled.

Anyone else tried LiveScripting with Meteor.js apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the other [`livescript` package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/livescript). I'm not sure why someone created the `livescript-latest` package - both seem to be using version 1.2.0 of livescript.

```
mrt add livescript
```

This worked for me back when I was using LiveScript.

Answer (score 1):

`meteor add vasaka:livescript-compiler`

https://atmospherejs.com/vasaka/livescript-compiler